# Why is locating Elements by CSS Selector in Python working only in some cases?

Tags: pandas, selenium

I am trying to webscrape a used cars website (https://www.webmotors.com.br/) and extract some information about their cars. I am using Selenium library and `find_element_by_css_selector` method to locate those information. My input is a specific car name e.g: "tracker" and for some cars, my code is running without any problems! But for some other models, my code simply returns error.

1. The class name always remains the same, so I don't understand why this error is happening.

Follow the code for both cases:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import os.path
from os import path
import pandas as pd

plan="WebScrapPrecos.csv"
FileExists = 1
if not path.exists(plan):
    FileExists = 0
f = open(plan, "a", encoding="utf-8")
if FileExists ==0:
    f.write("Nome;Modelo;Valor;Ano;Quilometragem;")

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get('https://www.webmotors.com.br/')
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchBar"]').send_keys('hb20')
time.sleep(3)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchBar"]').send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = navegador.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    navegador.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = navegador.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height


wait = WebDriverWait(navegador, 20)
actions = ActionChains(navegador)

#wait for the first element visibility
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-hMFtBS.cVTeoI")))
#extra wait to make all the other elements loaded before getting the elements list
time.sleep(0.5)

cars = navegador.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sc-hMFtBS.cVTeoI')

for car in cars:
    # scroll element into the view
    actions.move_to_element(car).perform()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    names = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-uJMKN.hNiOat').text
    models = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-bbmXgH.fEaLmM').text
    prices = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-kvZOFW.knsOia').text
    quilometers = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-hmzhuo.ezNMNH').text
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(names)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(models)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(prices)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(quilometers)
```

and follow the html print for both cases (1st working 2nd not working)

Working:

[image: working]

Not working:

[image: not working]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I can guess the following 2 things may help:

1. Add a wait / delay before getting the cars elements list
2. for each car details scroll that elements into the view.
   So the code will be as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

#wait for the first element visibility
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-hMFtBS.cVTeoI")))
#extra wait to make all the other elements loaded before getting the elements list
time.sleep(0.5)

car = drive.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sc-hMFtBS.cVTeoI')

for car in cars:
    #scroll element into the view
    actions.move_to_element(car).perform()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    names = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-uJMKN.hNiOat').text
    models = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-bbmXgH.fEaLmM').text
    prices = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-kvZOFW.knsOia').text
    quilometers = car.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-hmzhuo.ezNMNH').text

    f.write("\n")
    f.write(names)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(models)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(prices)
    f.write(";")
    f.write(quilometers)
```

Comment: Did the adjustments you suggested and still got the same error

"NoSuchElementException"

Will edit my question with entire code!

Comment: what attribute is not existing for the "problematic" car?

Comment: And the main question: why are you scrolling all the results to the bottom and only after that getting the data from elements? This is definitely not correct way.

Comment: This is an used cars website. The "problematic" car was a promo card. I solved this using " Try | Except"

Comment: I am not scrolling all the results to the bottom and only after that getting the data from element. The first two lines of finding by Xpath is just to search the correct model in the website. I only start getting data using "find_element_by_css_selector"

I am sure my code is not 100% optimized, I only have 6 month experience coding! If you guys have any suggestions on improving it I will thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first vehicle being announced in most categories was already a real announcement but for some vehicles, the first one was publicity, and so the class of the publicity in HTLM was different.